# Datastructure with equivalent power of heap and map

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, heap

I want to design a container C of element E.

E has 2 attributes (priority, name), All elements in container have unique 'name'

I want to support following operations on this container C as effeciently as possible.

1. insert:- inserts element1(name1, priority1) to the container:
   C.insert(element(name1, priority1))
2. update :- update priority of element with name=name1 as priorityNew1:
   C[name1] = priorityNew1
3. delete:-deletes the element with name=name1: C.delete(name1)
4. get and remove element with highest priority: C.pop()
5. get element with highest priority: C.peek()

Basically I want a combination of map and heap. map on element's 'name', and heap on element's 'priority'.
Most ideally I would like every operation as O(1).
Otherwise insert, update, delete as O(log N) and pop and peek as O(1) is also fine.

I could think of following two approaches

1) Using a hash map of elements, hashed on name.
so insert update delete are O(1) 
pop and peek are O(N), we search whole container for highest priority.

2) Using SQLite with table 'element' having two columns 'name' and 'priority'.
running times will be based on SQLite implementations.

I am interested to know more thoughts on this problem, I am facing a real world problem related to this.
Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: May be [Treap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap) data structure?

Comment: @Evgeny Uh, the treap depends on the randomness of the priority values used for the heap structure. The OP wants his own priority values.

Comment: It sounds like a [Boost bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) should do the job pretty easily. If you might want more than two key fields at some point, Boost multi_index can do that, but as long as you only want two, bimap is probably simpler.

Comment: "Otherwise insert, update, delete as O(log N) and pop and peek as O(1) is also fine." Than it sounds like a regular heap would be fine.

Answer (score 3):

If `O(logN)` for each operation is acceptable, obviously [`boost::bimap`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) will suffice. This works like a *two-sided* `std::map`. You can get almost the same by maintaining two `std::map` together or write your own wrapper (but why should you?). A binary search tree with self balancing has a `O(logN)` for minimal retrieval, which is slightly less efficient than a heap.

If efficiency is really that important, you should implement your own container with **both a heap and a hash map**. Then, maintain the mapping from `name` to subscription in heap array in the hash map as you swaps around in the heap. This gives insertion, deletion, reassign priority a `O(logN)` and minimal/maximal priority element in `O(1)`. (which is not a piece of cake to implement but not tedious either)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if Boost will work for you but I'd check out Boost Mutli Index.  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html

You could keep an in index on priority to allow you get at those quickly as well as insert Elements too.  I've used boost mutli index for MRU/LRU situations similarly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

struct bypriority{};
struct byseq{};

struct MyElement{
    typedef int priority_type;
    typedef std::string name_type;

    name_type name;
    priority_type priority;

    MyElement(const name_type& name, const priority_type& priority):name(name),priority(priority){};
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyElement& e){
    os << "Name: " << e.name << " Priority: " << e.priority;
    return os;
}

using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::multi_index;

template<typename Element>
struct Container{
    typedef multi_index_container<
        Element,
        indexed_by<
            //sequenced
            sequenced<tag<byseq> >,
            //ordered by priority
            ordered_non_unique<tag<bypriority>,member<Element,typename Element::priority_type,&Element::priority>, std::greater<typename Element::priority_type>  >
        >
    > Elements;


    void insert(const Element& e){
        typename Elements::template index<byseq>::type& list_view = elements.get<byseq>();
        list_view.push_back(e);
    }

    boost::optional<Element> peek() const{  
        boost::optional<Element> res;
        typename Elements::template index<bypriority>::type::iterator it = elements.get<bypriority>().begin();
        if(it != elements.get<bypriority>().end()){
            res.reset(*it);
        }
        return res;
    }

    boost::optional<Element> pop() {
        boost::optional<Element> res;
        typename Elements::template index<bypriority>::type& priority_index = elements.get<bypriority>();
        typename Elements::template index<bypriority>::type::iterator it = elements.get<bypriority>().begin();
        if(it != elements.get<bypriority>().end()){
            res.reset(*it);
            priority_index.erase(it);
        }

        return res;
    }

    void print_in_order(std::ostream& os) const{
        typedef  typename Elements::template index<byseq>::type elements_by_sequence;
        for(typename elements_by_sequence::iterator it = elements.get<0>().begin(); it != elements.get<0>().end(); it++){
            os << *it << std::endl;
        }
    }

    protected:
    Elements elements;
};



using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Container<MyElement> c;

    c.insert(MyElement("Bob",10));
    c.insert(MyElement("Alice",100));
    c.insert(MyElement("Fred",20));


    c.print_in_order(std::cout);

    cout << endl << "Highest Priority is " << endl << *c.peek() << endl;

    boost::optional<MyElement> alice = c.pop();
    if(alice){
        cout << "Popped results are " << *alice << endl;
    }


    cout << endl << "Now the contents are" << endl;
    c.print_in_order(std::cout);

}
```

Will output:

```
Name: Bob Priority: 10
Name: Alice Priority: 100
Name: Fred Priority: 20

Highest Priority is 
Name: Alice Priority: 100
Popped results are Name: Alice Priority: 100

Now the contents are
Name: Bob Priority: 10
Name: Fred Priority: 20
```